# Prevent Gmail from adding calendar events from emails

Tags: gmail, calendar

Every time I buy a plane or train ticket, gmail automatically creates a calendar event relative to the flight/train. I would like to disable this feature; I've already tried to do so from the google calendar options, but that didn't stop the calendar events from being created.

I suppose it's the Gmail app on my phone that does that, but I can't find an option to set to make it stop.

Comment: AFAIK this is already done in Google backend. Google scans all your E-Mails - see for example [this article](https://www.cnet.com/news/the-new-gmail-has-automated-scans-heres-what-you-can-and-cant-turn-off/) on that topic.

Answer (score 0):

Gmail scans emails and automatically adds reservations to the calendar to remind users of the upcoming events.

To stop reservations from being added to the calendar, you must follow the steps described in [Events from Gmail](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/6084018?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en&oco=1)

> 1. Open the Google Calendar app.
> 2. In the top left, tap Menu Menu and then Settings.
> 3. Tap **Events from Gmail**.
> 4. Switch off **Add events from Gmail**.